# 404 Not found when refreshing the browser with Tomcat 8 and IntelliJ

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea

I have a web app that i have made with `IntelliJ 2016` and deployed on `Tomcat 8`. The strange thing is that the page loads well when IntelliJ fire the browser and load the page, but if i press F5 and reload the page i get a 404 Not found from Tomcat... I am using `Maven` for the dependencies and `Jason` for the `Rest API`... I have notice a rare thing too in my `web.xml` file, in the `<url-pattern>` tag. That tag have "/*" as value and in the service (on the client) i call the REST API with the "rest/mascotas" url, no "/mascotas" only without the "rest" part... so i don't know why this works... I left you the servlet definition, the web.xml and the service in the client that call the servlet.

PD: I am using AngularJS for the client.

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
  <display-name>MissingDog</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Mascotas-Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.missingdog.services</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Mascotas-Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

MascotaService.java:

```
package com.missingdog.services;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.missingdog.dao.MascotaDAO;
import com.missingdog.model.Mascota;

@Path("mascotas")
public class MascotaService {

    @GET
    @Path("/")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Response listar() throws JsonProcessingException {

        MascotaDAO dao = new MascotaDAO();
        List<Mascota> list = null;
        try {
            list = dao.listarMascotas();
            System.out.println(list.size());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return Response.status(500).build();
        }

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        //Habilita el indentando hacia la derecha del codigo JSON generado
        objectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

        String output = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(list);

        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/{mascota}")
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Response guardar(@PathParam("mascota") String jsonMascota) {

        //Convierto los datos enviados por el cliente en formato JSON en un objeto tipo Mascota
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Mascota mascota = null;
        try {
            mascota = objectMapper.readValue(jsonMascota, Mascota.class);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            return Response.status(500).build();
        }

        MascotaDAO dao = new MascotaDAO();
        try {
            dao.guardar(mascota);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return Response.status(500).build();
        }

        return Response.status(204).build();
    }

    @DELETE
    @Path("/{id}")
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Response eliminar(@PathParam("id") Integer id) {

        MascotaDAO dao = new MascotaDAO();
        try {
            dao.eliminar(id);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return Response.status(500).build();
        }

        return Response.status(204).build();
    }
}
```

MascotaService.js:

```
(function() {

    var module = angular.module("missingDog");

    var MascotaService = function($resource) {
        return $resource("rest/mascotas/:args", {args: "@args"}, {
            query: {
                method: 'GET',
                cache: false,
                isArray: true
            }
        });
    };

    module.factory("MascotaService", MascotaService);

}());
```

Comment: It would be easier to find the problem if you could share a reproducible test case project.

Comment: it's difficult, because i can't even reproduce the problem myself. Sometimes the web app behaves correctly and sometimes don't... and i make changes and the same situation happens... sometimes it behave like all was ok and when i restart the server to run the web app again it fails... so i don't even know where to start searching for a solution

Comment: @CrazyCoder sry if i don't express myself correctly, i don't speak much english... but i would very gratefull if you can help me solve me out this problem... when i power on my computer today and run the web app and it works fine... but then i press F5 to refresh and it crash with a 404 from Tomcat... and even if i restart my computer the error persist saying that can't find the "localhost" resource, so i don't know how to handle this. Ask me what you need to know, i don't know what info to give you since i don't even suspect what can be the cause of the problem... thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what's the problem, maybe someone more experienced will be able to help you.